# Command not found (Linux terminal) Path settings

Tags: linux, terminal, simulator

I am working on a cache simulator and while execution i am getting the following error .
I am using Ubuntu terminal for executing the program.
I don’t understand the problem with error since i have all the additional files mapped to the main program.

do  i need to set path for the program to any directory to execute them?

At first for giving permissions i executed the following command so that i wont get "permission error"

```
enter code here
chmodx +x ./csim.c
```

And then i executed the following command for final program execution

```
enter code here
./csim.c [-hv] -s 5 -E 1 -b 5 -t traces/long.trace
```

errors in output terminal

```
./csim.c: line 1: /bin: Is a directory
./csim.c: line 2: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 3: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 4: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 5: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 6: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 7: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 8: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 9: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 10: cachelab.c: command not found
./csim.c: line 11: traces/: Is a directory
```

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to execute a C source code file, which the shell is interpreting as a shell script because you have given it the "executable" mode.

The first thing to do is to compile the C file, e.g.

```
cc csim.c -o csim
```

... and then run the resulting executable program.

```
./csim [-hv] -s 5 -E 1 -b 5 -t traces/long.trace
```

Comment: I did compile that , but i am getting error in a different way ,I have added math.h for pow in header file and all the necessary headers but                                                               In function `main':
(.text+0x601): undefined reference to `pow'
(.text+0x89a): undefined reference to `printSummary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: compiler not able to identify the pow and printsummary even though i proper header files are included ,is it possible to fix this main': (.text+0x601): undefined reference to pow' (.text+0x89a): undefined reference to `printSummary' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to link the source files that include the functions. As you have observed, you can link to `pow()` by compiling with the `-lm` flag. You will also need to compile and link the `.c` file that contains `printSummary()`.